# How to fix: The tcp server having close waits after client disconnected

Tags: c#, tcp, server, persistent

I am having tcp server which gets hanged with "Close_Waits". I need to have an example program which deals with the persistent connection from the client.

I have tried catching the exceptions and then closing the socket inside the catch. But no luck!

```
protected virtual void ReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var wrapper = (ConnectedSocketWrapper)result.AsyncState;
    try
    {

        int bytesRead = 0;

        bytesRead = wrapper.ConnectedSocket.EndReceive(result);

        LogInfo("Byte Read" + bytesRead.ToString());

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            LogInfo("inside Byte Read > 0 : " + bytesRead.ToString());
            byte[] dataRead = wrapper.Buffer.Take(bytesRead).ToArray();

            wrapper.ConnectedSocket.BeginReceive(wrapper.Buffer, 0, this.configuration.BytesToReceiveInReadOperation, SocketFlags.None, this.ReceiveCallBack, wrapper);

            DataReceivedByServer dataReceived = new DataReceivedByServer(wrapper.Token, dataRead);

            EventDispatcher.RaiseEvent(dataReceived);

            if (DataReceived != null)
            {
                DataReceived(this, new DataReceivedEventArgs(dataRead, wrapper.Token));
            }

        }
        else
        {
            EventDispatcher.RaiseEvent(new ClientDisconnected(wrapper.Token, "Read 0 bytes (client disconnected gracefully)", wrapper.ConnectedSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()));

            LogInfo("inside Byte Read = 0 : " + bytesRead.ToString());
            Close(wrapper.ConnectedSocket);
            Socket removeSocket;
            connectedSockets.TryRemove(wrapper.Token, out removeSocket);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Close(wrapper.ConnectedSocket);
        throw;
    }

}
```

I need to have a hung free TCP server which handles the requests seamlessly.

Comment: Which exception did you get?

Comment: I am not getting any exception. the clients are unable to connect and on wireshark I do see a reset for all the client attempts.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would inspect code and/or use this one [simplsockets](https://github.com/haneytron/simplsockets), it's quite readable.

Also check this one [MultiProtocolAspNetCore](https://github.com/davidfowl/MultiProtocolAspNetCore), it's about how to build `TCP` server on top `ASP.NET Core`.

Also read this awesome [TCP/IP .NET Socket FAQ](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html).