# Besty way to handle multi-socket in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, network-programming

All.
I am looking for the most appropriate way to do Multi-Socket Programming with C#.

One client must connect to 10 servers and share various data.
It sends and receives about 100 ~ 200bytes of data at each 2ms interval to each server.

I am trying to create 10 objects by placing a Thread inside the SocketClient class. Each object has a different server IP address.

In addition to Thread, I heard that C# has various solutions for concurrency (Task, Parerall, Async, Await).

Is there a better way in this situation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of how your system is meant to send and receive data. Then we can propose a solution.

Comment: Just download someones already built and well thought-out socket implementation. Anyway this question is not suited for stackoverflow, its completely too broad. and ps (no i will not give you a link or a recommendation).. please read the help on asking questions here

Comment: Read my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56662099/how-to-fix-the-tcp-server-having-close-waits-after-client-disconnected/56950280#56950280